# Rounding off a single corner of a cube

Tags: modeling

There's many guides and approaches to rounding off edges or multiple vertexes of a cube. But I have not found a resource showing how to take a single corner of a cube and beveling it.
The closest I have come to reaching my goal is shown here.

I want the top side of the cube to have one rounded corner while the opposite face remains square.
The second image is taking from the cubes bottom side. It have become rounded at one corner, while I wanted it to remain square.

The remaining sides of the cube must be rounded off accordingly too. Providing a nice rounded corner, that can be placed upon another cube and have all their edges touch.

I'm still learning Blender so forgive me if I have missed the obvious.

**Edit**: To try and illustrate what I am aiming consider the two red blocks. The bottom side of the blocks are squares. They have however been rounded on each left and the back side. The nearest corner of the cubes seem to have been smoothed out.

[image]
[image: Too vertexes]

Comment: Have you tried intersecting two quarter-cylinders?

Comment: Yes. If I interpret your question correctly I tried, however that didn't leave me with a square bottom side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the "smooth" look of the corner is just a matter of shading (and shaders).

I suggest to simply model it as a [cloister vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloister_vault)'s corner. Any distortion of the profiles in my opinion would lead to a worse result.

[image]

If your boundary profiles are round, you can use the **[Bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html)** operator on the two top edge (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). Then add two (flattened) loopcuts near the corner and Remove Doubles.

[image]

Then control the shading (set it to smooth) by **marking sharp edges**  and adding an **Edge split** modifier as you can see in the first picture.

Comment: "cloister vault" is a broken link.

Comment: This is solves my problem. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 7):

First, select the three edges that point from the vertex you want to bevel:

[image: select edges]

Select the cube, <kbd>tab</kbd> into edit mode. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> then <kbd>2</kbd> to select edges. Right click the three edges.

After that, start bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Drag mouse to change size of bevel. Roll mousewheel to change number of segments of bevel.
If you click and finish the bevel, you can still affect it to the lower left. See image here:

[image: bevelling]

Comment: It doesn't quite cut it because the bottom side of the cube needs to remain square. In your suggestion the bottom side of the cube has a rounded corner.
I've added an example of a mesh I'm trying to recreate in the original question.

Comment: I get that same result as Carlo if I bevel only two edges. But I think the shading is very wrong if it looks smooth. It is a 90 deg angle. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can get some result either using beveling or subsurface modifier, at least.
I'm just in doubt of what you mean with "The remaining sides of the cube must be rounded off accordingly too". Have you seen anywhere an example of what you want to achieve?

I tried something here, and can explain but I guess you could have a different idea:

[image]